# RxJava and Android

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I've been using the RxJava/RxAndroid libraries to do some testing, I get (or at least I think I get) the fundamentals and how it can ease more complex asynchronous tasks etc.

I have read and followed different tutorials, some make perfect sense while others are more complex where it chains 3 or 4 tasks/filters/maps etc together where, to me, it looks like a condensed mess (unless I'm writing the functional code myself reading others functional code is harder to follow than non functional code i.e. Lambdas).  Hopefully the more I read and try I'll have those break those breakthrough moments of clarity.

However one aspect I'm struggling with, and has been mentioned several times in information I've read, is the *'no need to use callbacks anymore'*, or *'no more callback hell'*.  In principal I get it - RxJava is (in essence, although its much more) the Observer pattern.  However Android is a framework that is all about callbacks, from `Activity` and `Fragment` life cycles, `Services`, `BroadcastReceivers`, ClickListeners etc.. they are everywhere.

I'm not sure how I remove the need for callbacks with a Framework that relies heavily on them.

I'm not looking for opinions as that would be too broad and the question closed. However if there are some personal examples, or links where RxJava 'made sense' to new comers of the library that I could look at.  At the moment it feels I'd be using RxJava for the sake of it, rather than fully understanding it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [RxBinding](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding) which gives you Rx endpoints for many Android classes. The hard work of rx-ifying many framework classes is done for you there. Just import the package(s) that are relevant to you.

It does take some time to develop the vocabulary. First you will learn to read the simple operators like `map` and filter` and in time and with experience (and reading of documentation) you will develop that vocabulary and understand other's code better.

Also check out [RxLifecycle](https://github.com/trello/RxLifecycle) to automatically `complete` your Observable chains and avoid leaked Subscriptions (which can leak Activities!!!). Remember that these will `complete` the `Observable` chain and not just unSubscribe it. i.e. `onComplete` will be called on your `Subscriber`.

Comment: Thank you for the links and suggestions, very useful, and ones I'd not seem before. RxJava does feel like a steep learning curve, but one I'll stick with as I can see the definite benefits of the library - cheers!